# how to get a data from an observable based on some parameter and then updating that data?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in firestore 'user' with documents having attributes

```
 users:{
    userId:string;
    userName:string;
    stars:number
    }
```

I want to grab the stars of a particular user and then update the stars of that user.
In my component I have a method that calls an observable to get stars and once that is fetched ,I want to update that stars value. But the issue I am having is that since getuserStars(userId) is running asynchronously my userStars variable is undefined before i update. Also i tried updating the stars inside the subscribe method but that run into an infinite loop as the data get updated and observable returns new data and subscribe is called again creating infinite loop.
any help?

```
let userStars;

 setUserStars(userId){
   getuserStars(userId);

   let starsCount=this.userStars+25;

   this.afs.collection('users').doc(userId).update({
    stars:starsCount
  }).catch(err=>console.log(err));

}

getuserStars(userId){
     this.subscription= this.afs.doc<User> 
     (`users/${userId}`).valueChanges().subscribe(user=>{
       this.userStars=user.stars;
     })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Read and Update are both observable-based operations, therefore if you want to execute them one after the other, you need to chain them via an operator, typically `switchMap`. Something along the following lines

```
function readStuff(): Obaservable<any> {// get stuff from source };

function updateStuff(stuff): Observable<any> { // update stuff on the source }

readStuff()
.switchMap(stuff => updateStuff(stuff))
.subscribe (
   returnValue => {// do something with the return value},
   error => {// handle error condition }
}
```

Then you may still have the problem of the infinite loop, but probably to get this solved you need to revisit your design